# How to get dates of a week (I know week number)?

Tags: java

I know the week number of the year, a week is start from Sunday, then Monday, Tuesday...,Saturday.

Since I know the week number, what's the efficient way to get the dates of the specific week by using Java code??

Comment: do you mean, given it is the 22nd week of 2010, what is the date of that first day of the week (with the week's first day being Sunday)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you don't want external library, just use calendar.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 23);        
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 37):

### Pure Java 8 / java.time solution

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32185901/1891695):

```
final long calendarWeek = 34;
LocalDate desiredDate = LocalDate.now()
            .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, calendarWeek)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
```

Comment: If you want to get by week of another year yo could use `LocalDate.ofYearDay(year, 50)` instead of `LocalDate.now()`. DayOfYear (`50` in my case) can be random but should be not earlier than the number of the first day `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` in that year.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library

```
int weekNumber = 10;
DateTime weekStartDate = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(weekNumber);
DateTime weekEndDate = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(weekNumber + 1);
```

Comment: This will not work if last week of year i-e '52' is passed.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 9):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution:**

The first step is to find the ***first day of the week*** and as the second step, we just need to iterate all the seven days starting with this date.

Note that the ***first day of the week*** is `Locale`-dependent e.g. it is Monday in the UK while Sunday in the US. As per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, it is Monday. For comparison, check the [US calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=1&wno=1) and the [UK calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=9&wno=1).

**Demo of the first step:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        int weekNumber = 34;
        System.out.println(getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.UK));
        System.out.println(getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, Locale.US));
    }

    static LocalDate getFirstDayOfWeek(int weekNumber, Locale locale) {
        return LocalDate
                .of(Year.now().getValue(), 2, 1)
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek())
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-23
2021-08-15
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/EAAJdG)

**Demo of the second step:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        getAllDaysOfTheWeek(34, Locale.US).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    static LocalDate getFirstDayOfWeek(int weekNumber, Locale locale) {
        return LocalDate
                .of(Year.now().getValue(), 2, 1)
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).getFirstDayOfWeek())
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber);
    }

    static List<LocalDate> getAllDaysOfTheWeek(int weekNumber, Locale locale) {
        LocalDate firstDayOfWeek = getFirstDayOfWeek(weekNumber, locale);
        return IntStream
                .rangeClosed(0, 6)
                .mapToObj(i -> firstDayOfWeek.plusDays(i))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-15
2021-08-16
2021-08-17
2021-08-18
2021-08-19
2021-08-20
2021-08-21
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ugdiQo)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: I do not understand what is the point of: `.of(Year.now().getValue(), 2, 1)` the values 2,1 can we put anything?

Comment: value 2 represents the Month, value 1 represents the day. Please make sure the day is always 1

Answer (score 3):

You did not mention what return type do you exactly need but this code should prove useful to you. sysouts and formatter are just to show you the result.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());
cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 30);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
System.out.println(formatter.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: anyway, you don't need the cal.setTime(new Date()) part.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty much same as others. But, here it goes:

```
int year = 2018;
int week = 27;
int day = 1; //assuming week starts from sunday
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setWeekDate(year, week, day);
System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1; i<=7; i++) {
            if(i <= 3) {
                LocalDate desiredDate = LocalDate.now()
                        .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 26)
                        .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.of(i)));
                System.out.println(desiredDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            } else {
                LocalDate desiredDate = LocalDate.now()
                        .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 26)
                        .with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.of(i)));
                System.out.println(desiredDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")));
            }
        }
```

This snippet provides dates starting from monday to sunday based on the given week number
output:

- 28/06/2021
- 29/06/2021
- 30/06/2021
- 01/07/2021
- 02/07/2021
- 03/07/2021
- 04/07/2021

To verify check https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2021