# How to get week numbers of a certain month?

Tags: java

I just wanna ask what is the efficient way to get the week numbers of a certain month. I have a function with month number & year as arguments, the return value of the function should be a int array which contain the week numbers of the specific month.(like following...)

```
public int[] getWeeksOfMonth(int month, int year){
            //what's the efficient way to implement this??
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear and accept answers to your previous questions.

Comment: duplicate of one of your other question you didn't accepted ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941700/how-to-get-dates-of-a-week-i-know-week-number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `WEEK_OF_YEAR` attribute of the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class can be usefull for you.

Create a new date that will be the first day of the given month. Get the week of the year for this day, let say you got `start` value.

Create a new date that will be the last day of the given month. Get the week of the year for this day, so now you got `end` value.

Finally, create a simple `int[]` that will contains values from `start` to `end`.

Comment: You dont have to iterate through the whole month. Just have a look at the first day's week, say `s`, and the last day's week, say `e`, and build the array holding `e-s+1` values from `s` to `e`.

Comment: @Flinsch Yes, you're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Flinsch: This will not work in all cases. See for example January 2010. The three first days of the year belong to week 53. The fourth day belongs to week 1.

Comment: You're right, sorry. So you need special case handling for `s>e` (which only may apply for january) as follows:
If `s>e`: build array like `{ s, 1, ..., e }`.
Else: build array like `{ s, ..., e }`.

Answer (score 6):

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int maxWeeknumber = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

Comment: This gives you how many weeks there are in a certain month, which usually varies from 5 to 6 (with the exception of february, which can be only 4 weeks)

Comment: But this does not work in one scenario where in is user change the Date format.

I have a open question on this only.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537895/need-to-get-correct-output-for-number-of-weeks-in-a-month-irrespective-of-what-d

Any answer on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether you want to return an array of length equal to the number of days in the month, with each value being the week number for the corresponding day, or an array of all **distinct** week numbers for the days in the specified month. Assuming it is the former, this should work:

```
public static int[] getWeeksOfMonth(int month, int year)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    int ndays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int weeks[] = new int[ndays];
    for (int i = 0; i < ndays; i++)
    {
        weeks[i] = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return weeks;
}
```

If you want an array of distinct week numbers for the days in the specified month:

```
public static Integer[] getWeeksOfMonth(int month, int year)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

    Set<Integer> weeks = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int ndays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    for (int i = 0; i < ndays; i++)
    {
        weeks.add(cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    return weeks.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

(Note this last example returns an array of `Integer` objects, but it is trivial to modify it to return an array of `int` instead)

Answer (score 3):

I think, that this is much simpler way:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("Current week of month is : " +
            now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Calendar instances for the
   first and last day of the month.
2. then on each instance invoke the `get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`
3. Step [2] will return starting and ending index for the weeks

Comment: Note that it can happen that (end index < start index).

Comment: hmm - how? as long as it's the same month we're dealing with, how can it be that the endIndex < startIndex?