# How to calculate week number for given date Android

Tags: android, calendar, week-number

I am trying to get the the current week number from the given date. i.e. If I enter the date as 01/03/2013 then i should get the week number which is 9..

Please help me in finding the solution..

Thanks..

Abhishek..

Comment: doing some google is must.

Comment: @pKs did alot of google already.. but not able to find anything thats why I have posted here...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4013917/1503130 I don't know where did I find this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a Calendar object for that date and get the week with:

```
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

The API is described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_YEAR

Comment: this code gives me the total number of week in that particular year. i.e. in this year there are 52 weeks. I don't want that. I want the number of weeks from the beginning of the year i.e. the week number till today is 9.. I want this thing not the total week..

Comment: I think you do something wrong. The following code returns 9 in my case.    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int week = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);

Answer (score 11):

```
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Log.d("Current Week:" + calender.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar sDateCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013,03,01);
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: Plase provide the complete code... Not able to find sDateYearAAAA, sDateMonthMM, sDateDayDD, iStartWeek and not able to get the sDateCalendar.getWeekYear(); method..

Comment: do you want for current date only or for any string you pass?

Answer (score 2):

01/03/2013 is taken in as 113 , 2 ,1

```
            Date d = new Date(113, 2, 1);

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            c.setTime(d);

            int weekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```