# Need to get correct output for number of weeks in a month irrespective of what date format being used

Tags: java, java-8, calendar, java-time, gregorian-calendar

I have this code which returns Number of week correctly.

```
package org.test.Calendar;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class GetDaysInMonth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        int year = 2020;
        int month = Calendar.MAY;
        int date = 1;
        calendar.set(year, month, date);
        int numOfDaysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int numOfWeeksInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);

        System.out.println("Number of Days In Month: " + numOfDaysInMonth);
        System.out.println("Number of Weeks In Month: " + numOfWeeksInMonth);
    }    
}
```

Output :

Number of Days In Month: 31

Number of Weeks In Month: 6

My Date format was :

[image]

Now when I change my Date format to :

[image]

Output is different.

Output :

Number of Days In Month: 31

Number of Weeks In Month: 4

Need inputs like **how can I get correct output irrespective of what date format are we using**?

Answering to the question how am I updating the format : 
a) Go to Control Panel -> Clock and Region
[image]

b) Select Change date, time or number format link.
You will get below popup, just change the format.

[image]

Comment: Not very clear as to how you are changing the date format to US/ UK. Not sure if its the image which is not getting displayed correctly.Can you specify in the code how this is being managed ?

Comment: I have updated the post with your question on how you are updating the date format, hope it helps.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Weeks are numbered differently in the US and the UK, so getting different results from `calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH)` is expected. How are you counting weeks? Do you want to know how many different week numbers can occur within the month? Also that differs between US and UK.

Answer (score 2):

Your results are as they should be. Since you expected something else, your expectations must have been wrong.

- In the USA the week begins on Sunday. Week 1 of the month is the week that contains the first day of the month. So Friday May 1 and Saturday May 2 make up week 1. Week 2 begins on Sunday, May 3. Week 3 on May 10, week 4 on May 17, week 5 on May 24 and week 6 consists of just 31 of May.
- The UK follows the international standard where the week begins on Monday and week 1 of the month is the first week that contains at least 4 days of the month. So week 1 is from Monday, May 4 through Sunday, May 10. Week 2 begins on May 11, week 3 on May 18. Week 4 is May 25 through 31 and hence the last week of the month.

In your code you didn’t query the number of weeks in the month. You queried the highest week-of-month number in the month. This is 6 in the US and 4 in the UK. Even though the month has the same length in both places.

### java.time

For my demonstration I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, with a recommendation that you do the same in your date work. The modern classes are so much nicer to work with than the outdated `Calendar` class, which frankly was always poorly designed.

```
    YearMonth mayThisYear = YearMonth.of(2020, Month.MAY);
    LocalDate firstOfMonth = mayThisYear.atDay(1);
    LocalDate lastOfMonth = mayThisYear.atEndOfMonth();

    // US weeks
    WeekFields us = WeekFields.of(Locale.US);
    int weekOfFirstDay = firstOfMonth.get(us.weekOfMonth());
    int weekOfLastDay = lastOfMonth.get(us.weekOfMonth());
    System.out.println("US week numbers are " + weekOfFirstDay + " - " + weekOfLastDay);
```

Output:

> US week numbers are 1 - 6

Let’s instead try for the United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland, UK for short:

```
    // UK weeks
    WeekFields uk = WeekFields.of(Locale.UK);
    int weekOfFirstDay = firstOfMonth.get(uk.weekOfMonth());
    int weekOfLastDay = lastOfMonth.get(uk.weekOfMonth());
    System.out.println("UK week numbers are " + weekOfFirstDay + " - " + weekOfLastDay);
```

> UK week numbers are 0 - 4

I should have loved to show you how to get the result that you had wanted using java.time, but even though I asked in a comment, you have not told us what you consider the correct number of weeks in a month, so I can’t.