# How to parse date from string with year and week using java.time

Tags: java, java-time

In old java I can do it in that way:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy w", Locale.UK).parse("2015 1"));
// shows Mon Dec 29 00:00:00 CET 2014

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy w", Locale.US).parse("2015 1"));
// shows Mon Dec 28 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

I would like to use java.time in Java 8.

```
System.out.println( LocalDate.parse("2015 1", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy w", Locale.US)));
```

Result:

java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015 1' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {WeekOfWeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=1, Year=2015},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

How to do it in java.time?

Moreover, I'm not satisfied that I have to pass Locale to determine first day of week: Monday vs Sunday. It is not country feature but calendar feature. I would like to use something like java.time.temporal.WeekFields.ISO to show the world that week start with Monday

I found similar case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941700/how-to-get-dates-of-a-week-i-know-week-number

but not for java.time in Java 8. Moreover, solution that first create a date object and later set correct week is not elegant. I want to create final date in one shot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Direct answer and solution:**

```
System.out.println( 
  LocalDate.parse("2015 1", 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("YYYY w")
    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
    .toFormatter()));
// output: 2014-12-29
```

**Explanations:**

a) You should use Y instead of y because you are interested in ISO-8601-week-date, not in year-of-era.

b) A calendar date cannot be formed by just giving a (week-based) year and a week-number. The day of week matters to determine the day within the specified calendar week. The predefined [formatter for week-dates](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_WEEK_DATE) requires the missing day-of-week. So you need to construct a specialized parser using the builder-pattern. Then it is necessary to tell the parser what day of week is wanted - via the method `parseDefaulting()`.

c) I insist (and defend JSR-310 here) on saying that the question when a week starts is not a calendar issue but a country-dependent issue. US and France (as example) use the same calendar but have different views how to define a week. ISO-8601-standard can be applied using the explicitly ISO-referring field `WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek()`. **Attention:** Testing has revealed that using `ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK` together with `Locale.ROOT` does not always seem to guarantee ISO-week-behaviour as indicated in my first version of this answer (the reasons are not yet clear for me - a close view of the sources seems to be necessary to enlighten the unintuitive behaviour).

d) The java-time-package does it well - with the exception that Monday is just specified as number 1. I would have preferred the enum. Or use the enum and its method `getValue()`.

e) Side notice: `SimpleDateFormat` behaves leniently by default. The java-time-package is stricter and rejects to invent a missing day-of-week out of thin air - even in lenient mode (which is in my opinion rather a good thing). Software should not guess so much, instead the programmer should think more about what day-of-week is the right one. Again here: The application requirements will probably differ in US and France about the right default setting.

Comment: Ad c) I was not precise.I meant that when I want to use custom Monday/Sunday settings then I should not use Locale where week day is defined as I want but explicite define what is first day of week. Proposed answer (with Locale.ROOT) is 100% what I asked

Comment: I applied the solution to year 2016:

System.out.println( 
            LocalDate.parse("2016 1", 
              new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("YYYY w")
              .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
              .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ROOT)));
          // output: 2015-12-28

Why I got 2015-12-28? I expect to get 2016-01-04, because first week of 2016 is 4-10 January

Comment: @michaldo Thank you very much for your feedback. I have changed my answer preferring the second solution. which still work for `2016-1` yielding the result `2016-01-04`.  It seems we have hit some oddity in the JSR-310-API.

Comment: I tried using this code with: "2015 52" and "2015 53" and got incorrect results. It returned the same date for both cases: 2015-12-21.

Comment: @DaveFord For me, the code above produces for week 52 the date 2015-12-21 and for week 53 the date 2015-12-28, which is correct. So I cannot reproduce what you observed.

Comment: @DaveFord : this code is locale sensitive. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584350/java-times-week-of-week-based-year-pattern-parsing-with-datetimeformatter.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted Answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932239/642706) is correct. Here is an alternate route.

## `YearWeek`

Use the [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class in [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. This library extends java.time with additional functionality. This particular class represents a year-week in the [ISO 8601 week date system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

The factory method `YearWeek.of` takes a pair of integer arguments, the week-based-year and the week number.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( 2015 , 1 );
```

## ISO 8601

Ideally you would be using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for strings representing date-time values. For [year-week that would be `yyyy-Www`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) the week-based-year number, a hyphen, a `W`, and two digits for week number with padding zero as needed.

> 2015-W01

The java.time classes, and ThreeTen-Extra classes, use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating strings. So life is *much* easier if you stick to the standard.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2015-W01" );
String output = yw.toString(); // 2015-W01
```

## Parsing integers.

You have a non-standard format for numbers. So let's parse your string as two pieces, one number each, to be interpreted as `int` integers.

```
String string = "2015 1";
String[] parts = string.split(" "); // SPACE character.
String part1 = parts[0]; // 2015
String part2 = parts[1]; // 1
```

The `Integer` class converts such strings to `int` primitive values.

```
int weekBasedYearNumber = Integer.parseInt( part1 ) ;
int weekNumber = Integer.parseInt( part2 ) ;
```

Now call that factory method.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( weekBasedYearNumber , weekNumber );
```

## `LocalDate`

As for first day of week, here we have been discussing the standard ISO 8601 definition of week. In that definition, Monday is always the first day, a week running from Monday-Sunday. Week # 1 contains the first Thursday of the calendar-year. In the case of 2015-W01 that Thursday would be January 1, 2015.

So, no `Locale` needed.

I am not quite sure of your goal, but it seems to be extracting particular dates for days within your week. That is quite easy with the `YearWeek` class and the [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html?is-external=true) enum.

```
LocalDate monday = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );  // 2014-12-29 start-of-week.
LocalDate friday = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY );  // 2015-01-02
LocalDate sunday = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );  // 2015-01-04 end-of-week.
```

[image: screen shot of calendar month January 2015 with ISO 8601 week number 1 running from 2014-12-29 Monday to 2015-01-04 Sunday]

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved by putting default parse value for Day of week using "ChronoField.Day_Of_Week"  and setting the value as "1" as follows:

```
System.out.println( "Date From Year and Week : "+
              LocalDate.parse("2015 1", 
                new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("YYYY w")
                .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
                .toFormatter()));
```