# LocalDate cannot parse 'ww' with 'yyyy'

Tags: java, datetime-format, localdate

I have to parse date using the following format: "201710" where 10 - week of year number. I tried to implement it in this way:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyw");
java.time.LocalDate startDate = java.time.LocalDate.parse("201710", formatter);
System.out.println(startDate);
```

But it throws exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '201710' could not be parsed at index 0
```

And after that I need to get first and last day of week from LocalDate object.
e.g "201710" - 05.03 12.03 (first day of week needs to be Sunday).

Comment: your code and your exception to not match up. the code says "201710", but the exception says "2017101". Maybe a typo?

Comment: just typo, exception is java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '201710' could not be parsed at index 0

I see "yyyyw" format is not supportable. What is the problem?

Comment: The new `java.time` classes seem to be just about as user friendly as the old ones.

Comment: @Kayaman, Please help with pattern.

Comment: @Kayaman, thanks for pointing to the other question. The answers there solve the problem when there is a space between year and week, not when year and week is one string of 6 digits with nothing to separate.

Comment: @OleV.V. no matter if my format is "201710" "yyyyw" or "2017 10" "yyyy ww", I still get exception.

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, you're right. I've got at least one working solution... anyway, here was the previous duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928720/how-to-parse-date-from-string-with-year-and-week-using-java-time

Comment: By the way, you might want to consider using standard [ISO 8601 format for a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): yyyy-Www such as `2017-W07`. Supported by the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library class [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer of @Kayaman is not correct because you cannot mix standard date representations (using yyyy = year-of-era) and week-date representations (using ww = week of week-based year). **The subtile difference between a standard calendar year and a weekbased year is relevant near the start or end of a calendar year.** Conclusion: Don't use the symbol "y", but rather the symbol "Y". Counter example for the input "201501":

**Correct solution**

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekBasedYear(), 4)
    .appendValue(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1)
    .toFormatter();
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("201501", formatter);
System.out.println(startDate); // 2014-12-29
```

**Based on the proposal of @Kayaman:**

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
    .appendValue(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2)
    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("201501", dtf)); // 2015-01-05 (wrong)
```

The resulting dates are different! The difference is caused by the definition of the calendar year which always starts on first of January while a week-based year always starts on Monday (ISO-8601-definition) using the first week of calendar year which has at least 4 days.

**Additional note a):** Java-8 does not manage adjacent digit parsing of localizible fields like the week-based fields (see also the associated [JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145633)), therefore I have chosen the builder-based solution instead of defining the pattern "YYYYww" (Java-9 promises a solution, however). But even with Java-9, a build-based approach is still necessary because of the need to define a default for the missing day-of-week (here: setting to Monday).

**Additional note b):** If you are looking for a true type for the combination of week-based year and week-of-year and use `LocalDate` just as a workaround for this missing type, well, you can find such a type in 3rd-party libraries, either in Threeten-Extra or in my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J). Example:

```
    ChronoFormatter<CalendarWeek> cf =
        ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
            "YYYYww",
            PatternType.CLDR,
            Locale.ROOT,
            CalendarWeek.chronology()
        );
    CalendarWeek cw = cf.parse("201501");
    System.out.println(cw); // 2015-W01
    System.out.println(cw.at(Weekday.MONDAY)); // 2014-12-29
```

Answer (score 2):

The (previous) [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928720/how-to-parse-date-from-string-with-year-and-week-using-java-time) works if there's a space between the values, however without a space the following parses nicely.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .appendValue(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.SUNDAY_START.dayOfWeek(), 1)
        .toFormatter();

System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("201710", dtf));
// 2017-03-05
```

Replacing the `SUNDAY_START` with `ISO` will give you weeks starting with mondays (so it will print `2017-03-06`).

Comment: @Will Graham, please check if you want year and aligned week of year. It’s consistent and unusual. You may want week-based year and week number. It’s a good answer in that it gives you working code that you can then tailor to your need.

Comment: I have given a counter example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## *ThreeTen-Extra*

The [ThreeTen-Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project adds functionality to the *java.time* classes.

### `YearWeek`

This library offers the `YearWeek` class that may prove useful to you. This class uses the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard [definition of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

If possible, I suggest you change your own strings to use the standard format: yyyy-Www such as `2018-W07`. The standard format is used by default in the `YearWeek` class for generating/parsing stings.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "2018-W07" );
```

But if you insist on your own non-standard format, we must define our own `DateTimeFormatter` to match your input. I took one line of the `YearWeek.parse` method from the [`YearWeek.java` source code](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.java), and modified to fit your case by disabling two method calls.

```
DateTimeFormatter f =
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
// .parseCaseInsensitive()
.appendValue( WEEK_BASED_YEAR , 4 , 10 , SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD )
// .appendLiteral("-W")
.appendValue( WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR , 2 )
.toFormatter();
```

Let’s try it.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.parse( "201807" , f );
```

> yw.toString(): 2018-W07

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).