# How to get a list of all week dates for the given calendar week in pure Java 8?

Tags: java-8, java-time

There are [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941700/how-to-get-dates-of-a-week-i-know-week-number) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689379/how-to-get-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates-in-java) of how similar things can be done using **Joda-Time** and old **java.util.Calendar**/**java.util.Date** APIs, but there are no complete examples of how it can be achieved using pure **java.time** API, without any additional dependencies.

There are also many examples, how to generate dates for the given two dates. But I was unable to found a complete example of how to generate a week dates for a given year and calendar week number.

Could you provide an example of doing this in pure **Java 8**/**java.time** API?

Answer (score 5):

### Pure Java 8 / java.time solution

```
public static List<LocalDate> datesListOfCalendarWeek(int year, long calendarWeek) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.ofYearDay(year,1)
            .with(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, calendarWeek)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));

    return IntStream.range(0, 7).mapToObj(start::plusDays).collect(toList());
}
```

Compare with Joda-Time solution:

```
public static List<org.joda.time.LocalDate> datesListOfCalendarWeek(int year, int calendarWeek) {
    org.joda.time.LocalDate start = new org.joda.time.LocalDate(year,1,1)
            .withWeekOfWeekyear(calendarWeek).withDayOfWeek(1);
    return IntStream.range(0, 7).mapToObj(start::plusDays).collect(toList());
}
```

And obviously, for any given LocalDate the solutions looks accordingly as follows:

```
/* Pure Java 8 / java.time */
public static List<LocalDate> datesListOfCalendarWeek(LocalDate date) {
    LocalDate start = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
    return IntStream.range(0, 7).mapToObj(start::plusDays).collect(toList());
}

/* Joda-Time */
public static List<org.joda.time.LocalDate> datesListOfCalendarWeek(org.joda.time.LocalDate date) {
    org.joda.time.LocalDate start = date.withDayOfWeek(1);
    return IntStream.range(0, 7).mapToObj(start::plusDays).collect(toList());
}
```

Comment: The constant `7` can be replaced with `Period.ofWeeks(1).getDays()`